# Design decision for a project

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, grails

[image]

Hi all,
I need your advice for a project. As you can see in the table there is client_id, user_id and date columns. This is a log book and it keeps the data for each user belongs to some company. At the end of the month I need a statistics about users and their usage of the system. So it will be like 
User 7 from Client 1 was enabled for 5 days last month
User 25 from Client 1 was enabled for 3 days last month
User 8 from Client 5 was enabled for 4 days last month ..... etc
Currently easiest method I found is something like

```
def logs = LogBook.createCriteria()
def result = logs.list{
    projections {
        groupProperty("user")
        count("user")
        property("client","client")
}
```

which returns something like

```
[User : 7, 4, Client: 1]
[User : 8, 3, Client: 5]
[User : 10, 3, Client: 15]
[User : 11, 3, Client: 16]
[User : 25, 3, Client: 1]
```

[0] is User object, [1] is count "count(user_id)" and [2] is Client object, do you have any idea to make this simpler or more solid? Or is it safe? Thanks for your advise.

Comment: Perhaps you should separate out the questions a little better.  Since the function is (apparently) a read-only query, its safety would seem to be limited to whether it executes quickly enough to avoid interference with other requirements (if that is even possible).  The main issue is correctness.  Does this do what you want?  You could import the data into a SQL database and do this "GROUP BY" query and many other report generation tasks, but it can scarcely improve on "simplicity" if you are able to summarize the data "in place".

Answer (score 0):

How are you looking to display the data? I would write a query for exactly what you want, make a class that grabs it with a resultSet, and write the set into a JTable.

Depending on the size of the Database table, you could return everything with * and then parse within the java.

Comment: This log book may keep millions of records and it can get really huge, since we do this project with grails I feel like I might have some performance problems, that is why I wonder if there is a better, quicker and solid solution.

Comment: i would start by narrowing down exactly what you want into a query. What type of stats are you trying to get, only days enabled?